# Angular pass array to another (NOT child) component

Tags: arrays, angular, components, sharing

Im fairly new to Angular and am having trouble passing an array to a different (not parent/child related) component. What I want in my app is to **click on a button to mark it as 'accepted', and to display that same array in a different view (the accepted arrays view)** , in a different route. I've **tried doing it with @Input and with shared Services** and it just wont work. Can you please point me in the right direction? Thank you.

```
sharedService.ts //My array is called 'Turno'

    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {Turno} from '../models/turno';


    @Injectable()

    export class SharedService{


    public turno:Turno;


        constructor(){

        }



setArray(turno){
    this.turno=turno;
}
getArray(){

    return this.turno;
}
}
```

first component (I mark an accepted array with the accept() method):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-turnos',
  templateUrl: './turnos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./turnos.component.css'],
  providers:[TurnoService, SharedService]
})
export class TurnosComponent implements OnInit {

    public turnos: Turno;
    public status;


  constructor(

    private _turnoService: TurnoService,
    private _sharedService: SharedService

    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._turnoService.getTurnos().subscribe(
        response=>{
            if(response.status== 'success'){
                this.turnos= response.turnos;
                this.status=response.status;
                console.log(this.turnos);
            }else{
                this.status= 'error';
            }

        },error=>{
            console.log('error');
        }

        );

  }

  accept(turno){

    this._sharedService.setArray(turno);
    console.log(turno);


  }
```

second component (receives and lists accepted arrays)

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from '../../services/shared.service';
import {Turno} from '../../models/turno';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-turnoaceptado',
  templateUrl: './turnoaceptado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./turnoaceptado.component.css'],
  providers:[SharedService]
})
export class AcceptedTurnoComponent implements OnInit {

        public turnos: Turno;


  constructor(
    private _sharedService: SharedService

    ) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.turnos=this._sharedService.getArray();
    console.log(this.turnos);
  }



}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for your SharedServices attempt?

Comment: Sorry, its done now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared service is the way to go in this case.

The service which emits the array every time a new item is added:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ArrayServiceService {
  private acceptedArray = [];
  public acceptedArraySubject = BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);

  addToAccepted(item: string) {
    this.acceptedArray.push(item);
    this.acceptedArraySubject.next(this.acceptedArray);
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

The service which calls the service to Add an item
(Ofcourse where you get your items from is up to you, and I'm sure you know how to pass an item with a click event so I'm not showing html):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArrayService } from '../array.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-component',
  templateUrl: './first-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first-component.component.scss'],
})
export class FirstComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  private allItemsArray = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  markAsAccepted(item: string) {
    this.arrayService.addToAccepted(item);
  }

  constructor(private arrayService: ArrayService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

And finally, the second component which listens to the changes inside the service and shows the accepted array:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ArrayService } from '../array.service';
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-second-component',
  templateUrl: './second-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second-component.component.scss'],
})
export class SecondComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  private acceptedArray: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private arrayService: ArrayService) {
    this.arrayService.acceptedArraySubject.pipe(share());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

And to consume the pipe in your html of your second component:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of acceptedArray | async">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this got you on track. So you have a service which holds the array you want, a component which changes it and another which listens to it. But you can have a lot of components listening to it or changing it..

Comment: thank you!! you are amazing!, I didn't know about the 'behavior subject "stuff, I'll look into it. Thank you very much!, btw: Do you know why my method with Getter's and Setter's didnt work?

Comment: @Ayrton you're welcome. In your code, you set the Turno object, but after setting object it doesn't do anything. So your shared service holds the new object and nobody knows about it. The getter for that object from shared service is only called once, in the OnInit function of the second component. After Initiation it doesn't get called anymore..

On the opposite, when you listen to a BehaviorSubject, each time .necxt is called on it, it emits the value to all the observers listening to it.

Comment: HI Cedric, I've tried the code and it does not work, it needs a starting value for the behaviorSuspect, which I declare as "undefined" but everytime I fetch the array from the 2nd component all It shows is 'undefined'. I cant find whats wrong

Comment: @Ayrton Hi, can you post an example on stackblitz? So I can see where the problem is? For BehaviorSubject instead of calling the type you can do this instead: public acceptedArraySubject = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly three ways for data communication in Angular.

```
    1. Using Input & Output for passing data to & from child component. 
       Also you can use ViewChild reference to access data (functions & 
       variables) of child component in parent component.
    2. A shared common service having setter & getter methods. 
       You can use it to set data. It acts as a temporary state.
    3. Using Browser storage in the form of session storage , local storage 
       or cookie. You can create one service which stores & takes in data 
       from browser storage & access it across components.
```