# Angular: pass data between components

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and am having trouble passing an array to a different (not parent/child related) component. So what I want to do is: when I select the rows from first component table, it will open new view and will show the selected rows.

First component:

```
openExecutionDialog(): void {
    ....
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result === true) {
        this.dataService.invocationBulk(new HttpParams(), this.checkedIds).subscribe(
          (changed) => {
            var taskids = Array.from(this.checkedIds.values());
            this.taskService.saveData(taskids)
            
},
          (error) => { 
            ..
      }
    });
  }
```

taskService:

```
public tasksSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Task[]>([]);
  data$ = this.tasksSubject.asObservable();
 constructor(
    private dataService: DataService)
  {}
public saveData(taskids: number[]){
    this.dataService.getTasks(taskids).subscribe((data) => {
      this.retryTasks = data;
    });
  }

setTasks(tasks: Task[]) {
    this.tasksSubject.next(tasks);
    debugger
  }
}
```

The definition of method getTasks is:

```
getTasks(taskId: number[]): Observable<RetryTaskResource[]> {
    return this.apiDataService.getTasksUrl().pipe(
      mergeMap((rootUrl) =>
        this.http.get<Task[]>(`${rootUrl}${taskId}`)
      ),
      map((result: Task[]) => {
        return result;
      })
    );
  }
```

Second Component

```
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
 constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {
this.taskService.data$.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = data;})
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="table-container">
        <table
          mat-table
          [dataSource]="dataSource"
          matSort
          matSortActive="zeitstempel"
          matSortDisableClear
          matSortDirection="desc"
        >


           <ng-container matColumnDef="modul">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>
              Module
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.module }}</td>
          </ng-container>

...
```

I've tried other approaches but no luck. When I work with debug mode I can see, that the tasks[] in the first component is filled.

**2nd Approach**
from [Angular pass array to another (NOT child) component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61292363/angular-pass-array-to-another-not-child-component)

First Component

```
...
(changed) => {
   var taskids = Array.from(this.checkedIds.values());
   this.dataService.getTasks(taskids).subscribe((data) => {
              this.markAsAccepted(data)
            });
 }

markAsAccepted(items: Task[]) {
    this.taskService.addToAccepted(items);
  }
```

taskService

```
 private acceptedArray: RetryTaskResource[] = [];
  public acceptedArraySubject = new BehaviorSubject<RetryTaskResource[]>([]);

addToAccepted(items: RetryTaskResource[]) {
    this.acceptedArray = items;
    this.acceptedArraySubject.next(this.acceptedArray);
  }
```

Second Component

```
  acceptedArray: Observable<Task[]> | undefined;
  constructor(....) {
    this.dataService.acceptedArraySubject.pipe(share());

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer data between components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71884418/how-to-transfer-data-between-components)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just keep using a service

in your first component:

```
onClick = () => {

  this.sharedService.array$.next( myArray );

  //open new view with dialog or router

}
```

then in your new view:

```
  @for ( let data of sharedService.array$ | async; track data ) {

    {{ data.property }}

  }
```

and in your service:

```
...
  array$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
...
```

EDIT:

The sencond approach is what I described above but you are missing a `subscribe()` method in your code
it should be something like:

```
  acceptedArray: Observable<Task[]> | undefined;

  constructor(....) {
    
    this.dataService.acceptedArraySubject.pipe(
      share(),
      tap( data => {

        this.acceptedArray = data;

      })).subscribe();

  }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately it didn't work. I think the problem is that inside the subscribe of the following code the array is not empty, but outside of it it is empty: this.dataService.getTasks(taskids).subscribe((data) => {
              this.sharedService.array$.next( data);

            });
 }

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar project where i have a list and when i select an element of the list a modal open with the selected content

main component html

```
      <div class="container-2">
          <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" class="card" style="width: 9rem;">
<img (click)="getInfo(i)" class="card-img-top" [src]="item.img">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{item.name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{item.types[0]}} {{item.types[1]}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

main typescript

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

..

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,) { }
  getInfo(index : any){

    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(InfoComponent,{data:index, width: '40%'});
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result)
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
```

and then the typescript for modal

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

...

  constructor (@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<InfoComponent>){

  }
...
```

using `data` you can send what you want, you can configure what you want and then send it